# How to import a module from different directory with Python 3?

Tags: python

I've tried to import a module for testing but received this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "BaseTest.py", line 8, in 
>       from .main.pageobjects.FBPage import *
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '**main**.main'; '**main**' is not a package

the project tree looks like this:

```
/- ProjectDir
/- .src
/- .src.main
/- .src.main.core
/- .src.main.core.BaseCode <- base code to be extended as parent
/- .src.main.core.pageobjects
/- .src.main.core.pageobjects.Module <- a module that inherit from BaseCode 
/- .src.tests
/- .src.tests.BaseTest <- main testing module
/- .src.tests.results
```

I basically did this inside my BaseTest module:

```
from .main.pageobjects.Module import *
```

What am I doing here wrong?
 :)

Comment: Could you please post what all other imports worked ?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 3.6.1

`import os,
import sys,
import unittest,
from selenium import webdriver,
from .main.pageobjects.Module import *`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to import specific class (or classes) under the Module. See the code snippet below.I have explained the logic below the code.

```
from src.main.core.pageobjects.Module.module1 import Module1
from src.main.core.pageobjects.Module.module2 import Module2
```

Inside the Module, I created two python files: module 1 and module 2; in module1, I created a class - Module1; in module2, I created a class - Module 2; and then I used the below code snippet to import the two classes in the package

```
src.tests.BaseTest
```

Click the link for the project structure screenshot. [How to import a module from different directory with Python 3?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUTiY.png)

See the python codes for module1, module2, and logintest under BaseTest Module.

## module1.py

class Module1(object):
    def **init**(self):
        print('This is a module 1 example')

```
def print_info(self):
    print("this is module 1 print statement")
```

## module2.py

class Module2(object):
    def **init**(self):
        print('This is a module 2 example')

```
def print_info(self):
    print("this is module 2 print statement")
```

## logintest.py under src.tests.BaseTest module

```
    from src.main.core.pageobjects.Module.module1 import Module1
from src.main.core.pageobjects.Module.module2 import Module2

m1=Module1()
m2=Module2()
m1.print_info()
m2.print_info()
```

Run the logintest.py and see the result. The result is from module1 and module2 in the src.main.core.pageobjects.Module package.

```
C:\Python36\python.exe C:/Users/SeleniumMaster/PycharmProjects/ProjectDir/src/tests/BaseTest/logintest.py
This is a module 1 example
This is a module 2 example
this is module 1 print statement
this is module 2 print statement

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I did the some thing as you described following your instructions and received the same error as before

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BaseTest.py", line 8, in <module>
    from src.main.core.Utils.setup import load
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a file called: `__init__.py` in /- .src.main.core.pageobjects. then in BaseTest.py add:

```
import sys
import os
os.chdir('../main/core/pageobjects')
current_dir = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(current_dir)
from Module import *
do_something
```

the code above adds this path  (/- .src.main.core.pageobjects) to the PYTHONPATH environment variable. Python uses PYTHONPATH variable to search for the modules that are imported , so once you add the full path , you can access the `Module` everywhere.

Comment: The __init__.py file should contain something in it?

Comment: @SysMurff No , it should be an empty file

Comment: Just added __init__.py file in all the directories that contains modules, but still same result and **not** same error:  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BaseTest.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ..core.pageobjects.Module import *
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Comment: please let me see the Error message

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "BaseTest.py", line 8, in <module> from ..core.pageobjects.Module import * ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Comment: the name of the module is not relevant, it happens on any module I try to import from this directory. Therefore, I edited the Error . regardless editing, the Error is the same on each module. @Alireza

Comment: Let me explain this to you by an example. For instance if you have a module in /home/USERNAME/module.py , you can add the path of the module which in this case is /home/USERNAME/ . To the PYTHONPATH so that it's accessible from anywhere

Comment: Ok. I'll try to find out :)